# High pitch shrieking when taking a shower in my bathtub that has a diverter

Tags: shower, bathtub, bathroom-fixtures

My tub has a spout to fill the tub if we want to take a bath, or a diverter which we pull up on to take a shower.  Recently, it started making this high pitched shrieking noise when we take a shower.  If I push the diverter down, the noise goes away.  When I pull it up again, it doesn't always make noise immediately but eventually, it will.

In my old place of residence, I lived there 10+ years but this had never happened during that time.  It too had a diverter in a tub.  The current place I've lived for 7 yrs and this problem started maybe like 3 yrs ago and has gotten worse recently.  I'm 90% sure it's the diverter but I just wanted to ask the community so I didn't change the wrong thing and break something in my tub faucet.

Answer (score 2):

IMPE it is not the diverter. It's the shower valve, and particularly the anti-scald mechanism in the shower valve. Again, IMPE, the squealing can often be stopped (for a time) by moving the shower valve either off/on or colder/warmer (without touching the diverter.) Notably, I've had it happen in showers without a tub faucet. In any case, next time it happens try just changing the shower valve setting briefly without touching the diverter.

Pushing the diverter down changes things by dumping a higher flow rate out the unrestricted tub spout rather than up through the showerhead with a lower flow at higher pressure.

A new cartridge in the shower valve will normally fix it.

Comment: Yetp, unless the diverter leaks (you get water coming out of the faucet), it won't be the diverter.  If it's not the valve, it could be cavitation in the shower head.  Should be able to figure it out by determining where the sound comes from—stick a screwdriver (or similar) on the valve or shower head and place the handle against your ear, and see which sounds louder.